# Data Generation - Java

Tags: java

I have to generate data for three fields **(field1, field2, field3)** that sum to `100`. The fields are double types rounded to two decimals.

Is it possible to have the fields generated following some standard distributions *(Normal, Exponential)* as they are all correlated?

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking for an algorithm to make sure that the three values are correlated (in which case you might be better asking in the statistics or probability StackExchange forums). Or are you asking for a java implementation of an algorithm you have (in which case provide the algorithm and your attempted implementation to date)?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to

1. create a list and add 0 and 100.00 to the list
2. generate `2` random double numbers and add them to list
3. sort the list
4. compute the differences between adjacent numbers
5. you will have 4 numbers and the first 3 are random numbers